# How to redirect to the same page with username after login in PHP

Tags: php

I want to redirect on the same page after login, but I need conditions like `if username and password come from index.php` then page will redirect to dashboard.php, `else it will redirect on the same page (exmple.php)`.

login.php:

```
<?php
include ('include/connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['loginform'])) {
    session_start();
    $email = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']));
    $passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['pwd']));
    $password = md5($passwords);
    $verify_query = "SELECT * FROM end_user WHERE (email='$email' AND password='$password')";
    verify_result = mysqli_query($con, $verify_query);
    if(!$verify_result){ 
        echo '<h2>Couldnot Process your request Please try to login after some time. </h2>';
    }
    if (@mysqli_num_rows($verify_result) == 1) { 
        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($verify_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }
    else { 
        echo '<h2 style="color:#CC3300;">Incorrect Credentials, You need to register <a href="signup.php" style="font-size:20px;" class="btn btn-primary">Here</a></h2>';
    }
mysqli_close($con);
} 
?>
```

index.php:

```
session_start(); // starts the session
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And I used the same code in `example.php`, so that I can get the URL in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: you can use header if no html has been sent to the client

Comment: you're mixing mysql apis also

Comment: and do **not** use this code in a live environment; it's totally unsafe.

Comment: your code is failing on you miserably and on too many levels.

Comment: you also have a **very bad** track record

Comment: thnx fr ur complimnt, m nt mkng u my judge....do u hv solutn thn gve........thnx

Comment: @Fred-ii- Translation: Thanks for your compliment, ***ERROR***...Do you have a solution....thanks.

Comment: @nitul Not a good idea to demand answers from someone with a high rep score on SO. My advice would be take onboard what Fred -ii said and attempt to fix or wait for the answer which may never come.

Comment: @Kitson88- yes u r ri8. Bt m nt vry mch flunt in englsh and nt exprt usng ths website. So my intentn nt to demand ansrs frm any1. if u fl lyk tht thn m sorry. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Your index.php login form pass an hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="extrafield" value="fromindex">
```

Then

```
<?php
include ('include/connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['loginform'])) {
session_start();
$email = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']));
$passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['pwd']));
$password = md5($passwords);
        $verify_query = "SELECT * FROM end_user WHERE (email='$email' AND password='$password')";
           $verify_result = mysqli_query($con, $verify_query);
        if(!$verify_result){ 
        ?>                
                                   <?php
                              echo '<h2>Couldnot Process your request Please try to login after some time. </h2>';
                                    }

                                       if (@mysqli_num_rows($verify_result) == 1)
                                     { 
                                      $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($verify_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(isset($_POST['extrafield']) == 'fromindex'){
                                    header("Location: dashboard.php");
        } else {
                header("Location: exmple.php");
        }
                                   }else
                                    { 
                                      ?>

                                    <?php echo '<h2 style="color:#CC3300;">Incorrect Credentials, You need to register <a href="signup.php" style="font-size:20px;" class="btn btn-primary">Here</a>                                  </h2>';
                                          }


                                mysqli_close($con);

                                     } 
                                                ?>
```

Comment: thnx fr ur hlp. In hidden field wht i  hv to pass to login.php?

Comment: and i also pass the value exctly wht u hv suggst me, bt its nt wrkng, its only redirect to dashboard.php, even i chnged the value "fromindex" into "fromindex11" in login.php page manually. bt its only redirect to dashboard.php

Comment: Use the condition I used after $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($verify_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); If user login from index page user will be redirected to dashboard.php and if user login from other page they will be redirected to exemple.php page.

Comment: Thnx sir, its wrkng....logic is vry smple, bt i mk it complctd by myslf. once agn thnx sir ji......